# Thank you response from HR, negative sign?

Tags: recruitment, human-resources, payscale

One recruiter called me said that I was shortlisted in their candidate list*(which I had applied some where like mid of 2015, and also I went to their technical and practical interviews)* and asked me to send the updated copy of CV and along with the expected salary.

I have replied but with some high amount of salary. *(Software Engineer position, in the range of $700 - $850 per month)*.

HR executive has replied to my email saying

> Noted with thanks.

- Does this response implies that I will be neglect?
- Should I want to contact HR manager and remind that I am waiting for
  any positive    response?

Comment: I find the fact that you applied in mid 2015 (e.g. more than 6 months ago) more troublesome that the wording of an e-mail response from HR. Unless you were aware of this timeilne from the beginning, it seems like too long a wait.

Comment: $850 per month is not a high salary. It would be far less than the norm for a software dev position in the US.  It isn't even the minimum wage required by law.

Comment: @HLGEM The OP's profile indicates that they are in Sri Lanka.

Answer (score 8):

**Short answer:** Just take the response at face value!

I think you're over-thinking the situation.  The email that you've received says exactly how it reads.  They have received your update, and they will take that into consideration when they move to the next step.

We all have a tendency to read the worst into any neutral response, but this really is just that - a neutral acknowledgement.  You'll find out more in due course :)

Comment: +1 - If anything this response is positive because it actually acknowledges receipt of the information. HR departments have the bad habit of not acknowledging receipt and become an information void more often than not.

Comment: @toadflakz Many places I've worked for have referred to HR as "the black hole" :)

Comment: It'd be ironic if this message back was an attempt to help Crazy Ninja not worry about "did they get my email?" and actually caused the same problem even worse..

Answer (score 3):

The golden rule when it comes to interpreting communication with a company or hiring manager: **take what they say at face value.** There is no point in trying to derive a deeper meaning behind a simple email or phone call. Even if there was some obscure hidden message, which there almost certainly isn't, you have no way of telling what that is.

They asked you for some information. You provided it. They thanked you to let you know they received it. The ball is still in their court and they'll get back to you when they come to the next step in their hiring process.

If, as you fear, the salary range you gave was too high and meant an automatic rejection, they almost certainly would have countered with the range they have for the position. Since they didn't, they'll evaluate the candidates they have left in their pool and go on to the next step, which could be more interviews or an offer.

**Do not reply back at this point.**

Comment: <3 the way you answer questions.